# Will JSON based REST - ESB - REST communication build AXIS 2 XML MessageContext

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a use-case for end to end JSON based REST services i.e. REST Client -> ESB -> Rest Service (all on JSONs) which I am planning to handle using APIs & PayLoad factory for transformations

1. In this scenario, will WSO2 ESB convert JSON into XML before invoking the target Rest Service?
2. If no for #1, then how will it prepare MessageContext object which looks having all XML constrcuts like SOAPEnvevelope, Body etc.?

**Update 1 :** To further clarify my question, I have updated this my sample API & custom Mediator

**api/TestRestAPI.xml**

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="TestRestAPI"
     context="/testrest">
   <resource methods="POST GET">
      <inSequence>
         <class name="com.example.wso2.esb.mediators.custom.MyCustomerMediator"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <class name="com.example.wso2.esb.mediators.custom.MyCustomerMediator"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

**Custom Mediator Class**

```
public class MyCustomerMediator extends AbstractMediator { 

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        System.out.println("In My Custom Mediator 44 $$" + context.getEnvelope().getBody() +"$$");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
In My Custom Mediator 44 $$<soapenv:Body
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>$$ 
In My Custom Mediator 44 $$<soapenv:Body
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>$$
```

I am getting proper response when invoking the API, however the printed Body of message context is not having any content.
So where is the JSON message being stored in MessageContext?

**Update 2**
My builder and formatter configuration in axis2.xml which were actually default in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 SNAPSHOT

```
<!--JSON Message Formatters-->
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                  class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
<!--JSON Message Builders-->
<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
```

The complete configuration file is available @ http://www.pastebin.ca/3038336
I have set **application/json** as the content type in the request to ESB API.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0):

Internally of the Rest API you will automatically have the content in XML. When accessing the api with rest data, it will automatically transformed to XML.

Then you can use the payload factory mediator to change the content. Then the response will automatically again transformed to json.

And that is what you need. So no "conversion" from your side necessary. Please create a specific REST API and post it here in case of an effective issue.

Comment: Have updated my question with REST API. To simply my question, I have removed payload factory mediator. As JsonStreamBuilder & Formatter are set, ESB should never try to convert them to XML. So now my question is where is the JSON content being stored on the fly (since SOAPEnvelope/Body is empty)

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario you only need to check first that appropriate JSON message builder and formatter are included in your axis2.xml config. 
In this case the original message will be parsed correctly and target service will be called with JSON.

Have not really used this format with ESB, but your payload should appear in body of the SOAP Envelope in MessageContext, as usual.

**UPDATE**

With given builder and formatter empty body of envelope looks to be expected result. As I see from the code, JSONStreamBuilder only creates empty envelope and saves reference to input stream in message context:

```
messageContext.setProperty("JSON_STREAM", inputStream);
```

So you can catch it with your custom mediator as:

```
messageContext.getProperty("JSON_STREAM");
```

But if you'd like to find JSON converted to XML, you need to use JSONBuilder instead.

Comment: Does that mean it will be still a SOAP XML message, but supporting JSON data? Then wouldn't it be a non-well formed XML?

Comment: Well, it depends on builder in fact. Anyway you will have envelope in your message context, but there are options about the contents of its body. This can be AXIOM XML structure or just a text for example. Why do you think non well-formed XML could be possible?

Comment: BTW, here is the doc about builders and formatters: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JSON+Support    Taking that you can select a builder which will convert your JSON to XML or the one that will not do it.

Comment: Please see my Update #1 above. I have already set appropriate message builders & formatters as mentined in the JSON support doc.  I am getting proper response when invoking the API, however the printed Body of message context is not having any content.
So where is the JSON message being stored in MessageContext?

Comment: Can you post your builder/formatter configuration as well?

Comment: Please check my Update #2. I have provided the configuration details. As I mentioned, I am getting correct response for the REST service. But I am just clueless where the message is stored in MC. Please let me know if any further information is required