# WSO2 ESB Custom Axis Module JSON Payload in MessageContext

Tags: json, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I wrote a custom Axis Module to sniff out all the communication within my WSO2 ESB. I have it registered in all phases - everything works as expected, when it comes to SOAP communication.

However, I am not able to retrieve the JSON payload of a REST API defined and called in WSO2 ESB. The MessageContext.getEnvelope returns an empty body, even though I can see a JSON payload being returned in my REST client.

Basically my code looks like this:

```
    public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
            String logId = msgContext.getLogCorrelationID();
            long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

            logEntry.setId(logId);

            if( msgContext.isDoingREST() ) {
                logEntry.setFormat(ILogEntry.FORMAT_REST);
                logEntry.setPayload(String.valueOf(msgContext.getEnvelope()));
            } else if( msgContext.isDoingMTOM() ) {
                logEntry.setFormat(ILogEntry.FORMAT_MTOM);
            } else if( msgContext.isDoingSwA() ) {
                logEntry.setFormat(ILogEntry.FORMAT_SWA);
            } else {
                logEntry.setFormat(ILogEntry.FORMAT_SOAP);
                JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(String.valueOf(msgContext.getEnvelope()));
                logEntry.setPayload(String.valueOf(json));
            }
    }
```

Is the JSON payload within `org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext` managed in a different manner than SOAP?

How can I retrieve it?

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you´re facing the same problem as described here.

[Will JSON based REST - ESB - REST communication build AXIS 2 XML MessageContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055149/will-json-based-rest-esb-rest-communication-build-axis-2-xml-messagecontext)

Comment: Hi - thanks for responding. I did look into that before posting this question. I am getting NULL when trying to resolve getProperty("JSON_STREAM"). I also came across a post mentioning "JSON_STRING" as property to look at, but that did not do it either... :(

Comment: Maybe the following helps, but I'm not sure.  // Getting the json payload to string
String jsonPayloadToString = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(((Axis2MessageContext) context).getAxis2MessageContext());
// Make a json object
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(jsonPayloadToString);